# Subdomain to folder htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am trying to point sub.domain.com to domain.com/app/*sub, but the farthest I can get is making it a redirection and I do not want it to redirect. Here is what I have, it works but it redirects it instead of staying on the subdomain, which is what I want.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/app/%1/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either redirect or force proxy behavior. See also [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse). To use mod_rewrite to proxy the request, use the P flag:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/app/%1/$1 [P]
```

You could also rewrite to /app/%1/$1 instead of http://example.com/app/%1/$1, but then the VirtualHost configuration of the subdomain would not be applied.

Comment: Looks like it worked but is this good practice? Does it put any unneeded strain on the server? Thanks!

Comment: If performance becomes a problem. I'd advise you to use a redirect instead.