# Redirect all subdomains to a specific subdomain with them as parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess rule file in order to host a laravel project in a shared hosting.

I use the subdomain app.myapplication.com as my subdomain. I would like all the requests to redirect like:

- testapp1.myapplication.com redirect to app.myapplication.com/testapp1/
- testapp2.myapplication.com redirect to app.myapplication.com/testapp2/
- testapp3.myapplication.com redirect to app.myapplication.com/testapp3/

My existing .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: *Redirect* so that the user sees the new URL? Or *rewrite* so the address appears to be the test sub-domain?

Comment: @Walf I mean rewrite, not redirect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subdomain to folder htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846842/subdomain-to-folder-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Below .htaccess code may will help you to redirect `testapp1.myapplication.com` redirect to `app.myapplication.com/testapp1/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^./]+)\.myapplication\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) http://app.myapplication.com/%1 [L,P]
```

Let me know if this is not work for you!

Comment: It doesn't work. With this code when I type app.myapplication.com/ it sends me to app.myapplication.com/app and when I type whatever.myapplication.com I get nothing.